# C-programming How to limit the printf to display ONLY the array elements that were filled with user input values

Tags: c

Maybe this is a silly question but I'm kind of new to programming and I can't figure out how to only print the elements of my array that where filled in the user input part. I just need to see what the user input. If you run the code you can see how the printf is displaying also the month and years that were not filled with user input.

This is the first part when I run the code:

```
Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes, n for no)
y
Enter rainfall inches amount for Jan-2011 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: 22
Enter windspeed mph for Jan-2011
Windspeed mph:
33
Enter rainfall inches amount for Feb-2011 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: q
```

when I input q the code will print alL the empty elements of the arrays including the elements of the array that are assigned. I don't know **how to limit the printf to display ONLY the array elements that were filled with user input**.

This is the part of the printout when you don't filled every month and year and after it goes through every element of the array, you get the values entered almost at the end:

...
Enter rainfall inches amount for Sep-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: Enter windspeed mph for Sep-2015
Windspeed mph:
Enter rainfall inches amount for Oct-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: Enter windspeed mph for Oct-2015
Windspeed mph:
Enter rainfall inches amount for Nov-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: Enter windspeed mph for Nov-2015
Windspeed mph:
Enter rainfall inches amount for Dec-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: Enter windspeed mph for Dec-2015
Windspeed mph:

Month    Year    Rain    Windspeed
Jan      2011    44.00   33.00
Feb      2011    77.00   11.00
Mar      2011     1.00    2.00

Total RainFall: 122.00
Average Rainfall inches per year: 24.40

Please try the Precipitation program again.
Press any key to continue . . .

This is my code:

```
#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//function prototypes
void inputdata();
void printdata();

// Global variables
// These are available to all functions
float Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = { "2011","2012","2013","2014","2015" };
char months[NUMMONTHS][12] = { "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" };
float sum = 0.0;
float windspeed[59];
int a;
float av = 0;

int main()
{
char enterData = 'y';
printf("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes, n for no)\n");
scanf_s("%c", &enterData);
if (enterData == 'y')

{
    // Call Function to Input data
    inputdata();

    // Call Function to display data
    printdata();
}
else {
    printf("No data was input at this time\n");
}
printf("\nPlease try the Precipitation program again. \n");
return 0;
}

// function to inputdata
void inputdata() {
/* variable definition: */
float Rain;

// Input Data
for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) 
{
    for (int month = 0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) 
    {
        Rain = 0.0;
            // Input Data rain and wind speed
            printf("Enter rainfall inches amount for %s-%s (without symbols) and hit enter.\n", months[month], years[year]);
            printf("Rainfall inches: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &Rain);
            sum = sum + Rain;
            av = sum / 5;
            Raindata[year][month] = Rain;
            printf("Enter windspeed mph for %s-%s\n", months[month], years[year]);
            printf("Windspeed mph: \n");
            scanf_s("\n%f", &windspeed[a]);
            a++;
        }
    }
}
// Function to printdata
void printdata() 
{
// Print data
printf("\nMonth\t Year\t Rain\t Windspeed\n");
int b = 0;

for (int month = 0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++)
{
    for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++)
    { 
        while (b < 60, Raindata[year][month]!=0.00)
        {
            printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\t %5.2f\n", months[month], years[year], Raindata[year][month], windspeed[b]);
            b++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// Print total and average rain fall inches per year
printf("\nTotal RainFall: %5.2f\n", sum);
printf("Average Rainfall inches per year: %5.2f\n", av);
}
```

Comment: Initialize `a = 0`

Comment: @CinCout `a` is already initialised to 0 because it is a global variable.

Comment: People can miss such things, that's why it is advised not to omit initializations and not rely on default ones! ;)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that code is inside the Print data and in print data I already initialized it as int b = 0;  Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I was referring to `a` which is used in `inputdata()`

Comment: "If you run the code you can see what's my problem". That's not the right way to explain your problem. Especially since your program requires so much input (you really expect us to enter 60 values which may or may not even reproduce the problem?). Please give the input used, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: My bad @kaylum when you run the code you can just input the first two values and next input q to exit the loop and you will see the output. Thanks

Comment: Still, that's not good enough. The "problem" I see may not be the problem you have in mind. Please don't make us guess. It wastes time. Just explicitly provide the input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @kaylum This is the first part when a run the code:

Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes, n for no)
y
Enter rainfall inches amount for Jan-2011 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: 22
Enter windspeed mph for Jan-2011
Windspeed mph:
33
Enter rainfall inches amount for Feb-2011 (without symbols) and hit enter.
Rainfall inches: q

when i input q the code will print al the empty elements of the arrays and the elements of the array that are assigned. Y don't know how to limit the printf to display only the array elements with positive value.

Comment: Sigh. Put the info into the question itself not in comments. Comments can be missed and cannot be properly formatted (as you can see for yourself - that output is unreadable in the comment).

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:` [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- I am voting to close your question because it does not meet that standard.

Comment: `while (b < 60, Raindata[year][month]!=0.00)`  --> `if (b < 60 && Raindata[year][month]!=0.00)`

Answer (score 3):

The only issues found are (1) the code should not have compiled due to the syntax error in your `while (b < 60 && Raindata[year][month] != 0.00)` (you had a `,` instead of `&&`) and (2) your failure to validate user input.

When you fail to check the return of `scanf_s` (or any of the `scanf` family) you have no idea if your code is processing garbage from that point forward. Always (*always*) validate user input.

A cleaned version of your code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5

/* globals */
float Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = { "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015" };
char months[NUMMONTHS][12] =
    { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
"Nov", "Dec" };
float sum = 0.0;
float windspeed[59];
int a;
float av = 0;

/* prototypes */
void inputdata ();
void printdata ();

int main (void) {

    char enterData = 'y';
    printf ("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y/n)\n");
    if (scanf ("%c%*c", &enterData) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (precip data).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (enterData == 'y') {
        inputdata ();   /* call function to input data */
        printdata ();   /* call function to print data */
    }
    else
        printf ("No data was input at this time\n");

    printf ("\nPlease try the Precipitation program again. \n");
    return 0;
}

void inputdata ()
{
    float Rain;

    for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
        for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
            Rain = 0.0;

            printf ("Enter rainfall inches amount for %s-%s (without symbols)\n",
                months[month], years[year]);
            printf ("Rainfall inches: ");
            if (scanf (" %f", &Rain) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (rainfall).\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            sum = sum + Rain;
            av = sum / 5;
            Raindata[year][month] = Rain;

            printf ("Enter windspeed mph for %s-%s\n", months[month],
                    years[year]);
            printf ("Windspeed mph: ");
            if (scanf (" %f", &windspeed[a]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (windspeed).\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
}

void printdata ()
{
    printf ("\nMonth\t Year\t Rain\t Windspeed\n");
    int b = 0;

    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
            while (b < 60 && Raindata[year][month] != 0.00) {
                printf ("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\t %5.2f\n", months[month],
                        years[year], Raindata[year][month], windspeed[b]);
                b++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("\nTotal RainFall: %5.2f\n", sum);
    printf ("Average Rainfall inches per year: %5.2f\n", av);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rain < dat/rain.dat

<snip>
Month    Year    Rain    Windspeed
Jan      2011     9.00   12.00
Jan      2012    11.00   19.00
Jan      2013    14.00    2.00
Jan      2014    10.00   17.00
Jan      2015     2.00    6.00
Feb      2011     2.00    5.00
Feb      2012    15.00    4.00
Feb      2013     1.00   19.00
Feb      2014    11.00    7.00
Feb      2015    15.00    9.00
Mar      2011     5.00    8.00
Mar      2012     3.00   22.00
Mar      2013     3.00   19.00
Mar      2014     1.00   24.00
Mar      2015     8.00   28.00
<snip>
Nov      2011     5.00   29.00
Nov      2012    14.00   18.00
Nov      2013    10.00    4.00
Nov      2014     1.00    7.00
Nov      2015     3.00   30.00
Dec      2011     6.00   17.00
Dec      2012     8.00   27.00
Dec      2013     7.00    1.00
Dec      2014    14.00   28.00
Dec      2015     4.00    9.00

Total RainFall: 444.00
Average Rainfall inches per year: 88.80

Please try the Precipitation program again.
```

**note:** I don't have `scanf_s`, so I have used `scanf` above.

For testing, input file `rain.dat` was generated with the following if you would like to test in a similar fashion:

```
$ echo y > dat/rain.dat
$ for i in `seq 1 60`; do \
  printf "%s %s\n" $((RANDOM % 15 + 1)) $((RANDOM %30 + 1)) >> \
  dat/rain.dat; done
```

A copy of the actual file used was:

```
y
9 12
2 19
5 2
9 17
12 6
11 5
9 4
6 19
2 7
5 9
5 8
6 22
11 19
15 24
3 28
8 11
2 17
6 28
3 22
15 21
4 25
11 28
14 16
8 22
14 4
1 18
3 21
1 29
2 30
14 4
4 21
7 20
7 27
3 17
10 24
7 29
10 24
11 30
1 25
7 6
13 14
15 30
11 15
5 27
6 3
8 25
1 29
14 22
2 23
15 19
8 29
2 18
14 4
2 7
13 30
12 17
5 27
8 1
3 28
4 9
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. This will work if I assume that the user has the data to input for each month and each year. But if the user has no data for example for feb 2013, I want to allow him to skip that month and to continue to the next input. If he did not have data to input for year 2015, I want to allow him to get out of the loop "q" and then print the data only for the months hi entered. In other words, to display or print only the elements of the array that he filled with his input.

Comment: Well, that takes rearranging the input routine. One way to handle no input for `Rain` or `windspeed` is to leave the tests as is and replace the `error` message with `warning` and instead of `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);`, simply set `Rain = 0;` or `windspeed[a] = 0;`. That will allow you to take data for *both*, for *either one* or for *neither*.

Comment: I keep getting the "...Enter rainfall inches amount for Sep-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter. Rainfall inches: Enter windspeed mph for Sep-2015 Windspeed mph: Enter rainfall inches amount for Oct-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter. Rainfall inches: Enter windspeed mph for Oct-2015 Windspeed mph: Enter rainfall inches amount for Nov-2015 (without symbols) and hit enter. Rainfall inches:"  after I input "q". This are the empty array elements. I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: If you use `continue` for either `Rain` or `windspeed`, you sill skip to the next month. (Remember `continue` will omit processing the remainder of the current iteration from *the point it is called* forward.)  Let me know if you are still stuck and I'll write an example.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you are using scanf wrongly. If you use scanf with the %f conversion specifier and you give it a letter ('q' for example), it will fail. You can verify by checking the output of scanf.

BUT this failure will also keep that last input in the scanf buffer if you don't explicitly flush the buffer. This means that each time that scanf statement runs, it automatically takes that 'q' value you fed it without prompting you.

A better way of going about this would be to do this:

```
if ( scanf_s("%f", &Rain) < 1)
{
  return;
}
sum = sum + Rain;
```

This would be a convoluted and not recommended method of allowing you use any non-numeric character or string to stop the request.

Now, it would be a much better idea to do something more like this:

```
<start of input function>

char rain_s[MAX_STRING_SIZE_EXPECTED];
.
.
.
scanf_s("%s", &Rain_s) < 1
if (strcmp(Rain_s)."q")
{
  return;
}
else
{
  Rain = atof(Rain_s)
}

sum = sum + Rain;
.
.
.
```

This method would ensure you don't run into any future problems.

Now instead of reading in a floating point value, you are reading in a string. You are doing a check to see if the user actually wants to quit and didn't just have a typo, and then you are converting that string into a floating point value which you can then use elsewhere.

Edit:
And while the comma you have in your while statement is not a syntax error, that is most likely still a programming error. Essentially, only the second expression is evaluated for the if statement.